# python 2.7 and subprocess() not passing args correctly

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

This works from /bin/bash command line …

```
$ /usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --topic AsIs-CalculatedMeasure --broker-list wrlmr4:9092 < /tmp/dataFile
```

'[' 0 -eq 0 ']'

When I invoke python's subprocess, it chokes on my arguments, I've changed the arg order, it always causes a choke on the first "—arg"

```
kafkaProducer='/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer'
cmdLineArgs = []
cmdLineArgs.append(kafkaProducer)
cmdLineArgs.append("""--broker-list wrlmr4:9092""")
cmdLineArgs.append("""--topic %s""" % ('AsIs-CalculatedMeasure'))
print 'Calling subprocess(%s)'%(cmdLineArgs)
cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmdLineArgs, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
# now write the input file to stdin ...
cmd.stdin.write(payload)


Calling subprocess(['/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer', '--broker-list wrlmr4:9092', '--topic AsIs-CalculatedMeasure'])
```

Stderr:  broker-list wrlmr4:9092 is not a recognized option

subprocess seems to be eating the "--" from "--broker-list" .. I've switched arg order and it gives same error "--" get eaten, I also tried "--" to no avail.

Comment: Use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to split and quote command line args, don't do it by hand. Without looking too closely at your code, I'd wager that's where your problem lies.

Comment: The `--broker-list` and `--topic` options might be logically connected to their values, but the option and the value are still supposed to be separate command-line arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you pass one big string with all arguments, protecting spaces by quotes, like this:

```
subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list wrlmr4:9092 --topic AsIs-CalculatedMeasure', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or you split the command line properly.
You passed two parameters as one, subprocess added quotes around them to protect them, and your called program failed to parse the arguments.

When performing its getopt or whatever, your called program expected:

`--broker-list` as argument n
`wrlmr4:9092` as argument n+1

But subprocess protected the argument since it had space in it so your called program recieved

`--broker-list wrlmr4:9092` as argument n

and it did not like it at all :)

fix your cmdLineArgs preparation like this

```
cmdLineArgs.extend(["--broker-list","wrlmr4:9092"])
cmdLineArgs.extend(["--topic","AsIs-CalculatedMeasure"])
```

I generally recommend the second approach, mostly if the parameters come from a caller, and may contain spaces. `subprocesses.Popen` will do the quoting for you.

Comment: Hey Jean-Francois .... thanks, I should have tried this but didn't .... many thanks!

Comment: My pleasure: I'm used to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044114/java-runtime-exec-cmd-c-parsing-quoted-arguments/39044198#39044198 (answered today). Seems that problem happens in all languages.

Comment: I was just chatting with colleagues .... since the called program is probably using getopt() to process the args. it needs the argv to be set as individual arguments than me 'bundling' them together.